# Adsense Bot looks for files for Adsense Matched content feature

Tags: adsense

Since i have implemented Matched content feature the Adsense bot (Mediapartners-Google) is looking for this tree files:

```
/google_matched_content_blacklist.txt
/google_matched_content_whitelist.txt
/google_matched_content_rules.xml
```

The file names sound like to control the Matched content feature,
but i can't find any description or documentation about this tree files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample of the /google_matched_content_rules.xml:

```
<rules>
  <blacklist>
    <uri>*.my-domain.com/exclude/*</uri>
  </blacklist>
  <whitelist>
    <uri>*.my-domain.com/include/*</uri>
  </whitelist>
  <section>
    <source>
      <uri>*.my-domain.com/cat1/*</uri>
    </source>
    <target>
      <uri>*.my-domain.com/cat2/*</uri>
    </target>
  </section>
</rules>
```

And the both files `/google_matched_content_blacklist.txt` and `/google_matched_content_whitelist.txt` are simple textfiles with a list of files or directories to exclude / include site in the related content.

**! Keep Care: This is still not official documented !**

Comment: What is your source for this? I crawled the Alexa Top 1 Million list and found the same information (plus [some additional rules](https://ctrl.blog/entry/adsense-matched-content-exclusions) you didn’t mention here). There were only a handful of implementers scattered across the web. Notably not from any large publishers.

Comment: Yeah, it is still not deployed. Google is testing that. But i have tested and blacklist works. I think we will wait for the oficial anouncment. If something goes wrong during this test phase you Website will have problem. Like Google use white- insteed of blacklist ;-)

Comment: the bot have been crawling these files daily for nearly half a year. I'm not really sure if they ever want to make any part of public announcement.

Comment: I have ask Google Adsense via Twitter: https://twitter.com/lovntol/status/835145014749573120